# azurewebsites.net built-in certificate

Tags: azure, ssl, certificate

I have created web apps in Azure which use the built-in certificate for ***.azurewebsites.net**. SSL works fine here.

I have recently created another web app and the certificate it is using is **MYSITE.azurewebsites.net**. This certificate has a completely different chain than the other one--the root of which is not trusted on my machine.

Can anyone explain why one site would use the wildcard and the other one wouldn't? Also, why would the certificate chain be different?

(The wildcard cert has a DigiCert root, whereas the site-specific domain (MYSITE.azurewebsites.net)  has a Cisco umbrella Root CA)

Comment: "Can anyone explain why one site would use the wildcard and the other one wouldn't? Also, why would the certificate chain be different?" It does not matter which certificate is used (and if the chains are different) as long as it validates (not expired, matching hostname, full chain of trust up to known root CA).

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Yes, it does matter. One certificate is installed by default on Windows 10, the other is not. So therefore, the typical Windows 10 user will not be able to visit the site!!!

Comment: Certificates are sent by the server... They do not have to be installed on the client, except for their root CA.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Correct. The root certificate of Cisco Umbrella is not installed on Windows 10 be default. That is the problem!!!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote Azure Support an got in contact with their Azure Web App Product Group. They gave me the following message

> This Cisco Umbrella certificate is not coming from Azure. You doesn’t have any SSL binding nor uploaded any certificate into your subscription.
>
> Most likely your client machine is in a network protected by Cisco Umbrella product. Kindly contact to Cisco Umbrella product support team.
>
> Another option to resolve this issue is to bind a custom domain and add a SSL certificate (Free or App Service or any other certificate) so that you do not use .azurewebsites.net URL.
>
> I am providing you relevant articles which will give you all the details about adding custom domain and binding SSL to your App Service.
>
> You can go through them once and then feel free to reach out to me if you have any questions or concerns
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/manage-custom-dns-buy-domain -> Buy a custom domain name for your Azure App Service.
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain -> Add custom domain to your Azure App Service.
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate-> Bind SSL certificate

Comment: I am currently facing the same issue and I have opened a ticket with Azure Support. In my case, the certificate that was assigned is only valid for 5 days and, at this moment, cannot be verified by an certificate authorities. I am very confused why would the Cisco Umbrella certificate be assigned to my Web App Service I have just created in Azure Portal. I had no VPNs connected at the time.